# Using SSL with nginx and Ubuntu on AWS EC2 is not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

I'm struggling with setting up a SSL for my EC2 instance on Ubuntu, I did it without any problems on Amazon AMI, but I have some problems with Ubuntu:

1. ✅ Added 443 port for SSL in Security groups
2. ✅ Generated letsencrypt key via `certbot`
3. ✅ Redirected http request to the https in `nginx.conf`
4. ✅ Restarted `nginx`

And I have timeout when I'm accessing my site via https, **could help me with debugging this issue**?

Here is my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  root /home/ubuntu/myproject;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000";
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Note: Everything is working via HTTP when I'm disabling redirect in nginx.

Comment: Why have you included this listen [::]:443 ssl;??

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth this line of config is included in many tutorials of configuring ubuntu & nginx & SSL that's why ;) Anyway, removing it won't help.

Comment: There is no issue as such with your configuration.

Comment: Check this example https://medium.com/@victorleungtw/enable-https-on-aws-ec2-instance-with-node-js-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-server-15dad4864e11

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I've tried this example, but still without any success, that's why I'm looking for debugging way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said this configuration was ok, I've terminated an instance and reinstall nginx and works properly right now.